# IIS Rewrite is not matching plus sign in URL Path

Tags: iis, rewrite

I have the below IIS rewrite rule,

```
 <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
```

This rule works all time. Except when we have URL in path like, `/A%2BD`.

So, `/ABD` is working but `/A%2BD` not. In logs I see

```
sc-status: 404
sc-substatus: 11
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found I have to add for fixing 404.11 HTTP Status,

```
<security>
        <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true"/>
    </security>
```